# How to count only enabled product from product_link collection

Tags: product, magento-1, collection

I've found in a template file, a code like the one below:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId());
```

It's used to display additional tabs in product view `if($collection->count())`, the problem is that it doesn't care if products in collection are enabled or disabled.

What would be the easiest way to count, using "the same code", only the enabled products?

Answer (score 0):

I only see two solutions here, but none of them are ideal in terms of performance I think.

### Solution 1 : dirty loop and count

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($collection as $product) {
     if ($product->getStatus() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
         $count++;
     }
}
```

### Solution 2: use another collection

```
$clone = clone $collection;
$clone->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$count = $clone->getSize();
```

Comment: Solution 1 as you said,  is not a good idea, the second, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure if thats possible at all.

Use this to get enabled products only

```
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
    'catalog_product_entity_int',
    // note this join clause! Here main table is catalog_product_link
    'main_table.product_id = catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id'
)
->where("attribute_id = 80 and catalog_product_entity_int.value= 1");
```

Or `go through the loop find all enabled products. Store in an array. Get a count. Or use increment operator like Raphael says.`

Comment: It doesn't work, it throws 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

Comment: Updated my answer. `catalog_product_entity_int` stores the status for products. You need to join that table and filter your collection based on that.

Comment: I tried, but it "doesn't" work as I spected, look, this is the  query I got:

SELECT `main_table`.*, `catalog_product_entity_int`.* FROM `catalog_product_link` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` ON main_table.product_id = catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id WHERE (product_id = '173031') AND (catalog_product_entity_int.value=1)

Look at the screenshot table in top is the result of the query, below the "product", the attribute_id 80 is the status
https://i.imgur.com/WoENI6y.png

Comment: Well i think there should be another condition in where clause. Try now.